# Listar Datos MySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una lista de nombres, email y mensaje que deseo mostrar, mi problema es que al mostrarlo solo se muestra el primero de los registros y se repite infinidad de veces.

Adjunto el codigo:

```
<?php
//Conectar con el servidor
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','USER','PASS');
if(!$link){
    echo'No se pudo establecer conexion con el servidor:'.mysql_error();
}else{
    //Seleccionamos Base de datos
    $base=mysqli_select_db($link, 'DATABASE');
    if(!$base){
        echo'No se encontro la base de datos:'.mysqli_error();
    }else{
    //Sentencia SQL
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM datos";
    $ejecuta_sentencia = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(!ejecuta_sentencia){
        echo'Hay un error en la sentencia SQL:' .mysqli_error();
    }else{
    //Traer los resultados como array para poder imprimir
        $lista_usuarios = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);
        if(!lista_usuarios){
            echo'Error al mostrar lista de usuarios:' .mysqli_error();
        }
    }

    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
        <title>Listado de Usuarios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Mostrando Usuarios desde Base de Datos</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Correo Electronico</th>
                <th>Mensaje</th> <?php
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia))
                         for($i=1; $i<$lista_usuarios; $i++)
                        {   
                        echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['nombres']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['message']."</td>";
                            echo"<td></td>";
                        echo"</tr>";
                        }

                    ?>

            <tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Estoy comenzando en el mundo de PHP, les agradecería su enorme ayuda.

Comment: No necesitas el for dentro de el while

Comment: Hay manera de mostrar TODOS los registros? Acabo de sacar el for del while y me muestra 2 de 3 registros..

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que no necesitas el `for` loop dentro de el `while`.  El `while` ya itera sobre todos los registros.  Ademas estas leyendo el primer registro antes de empezar el loop.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
<?php
//Conectar con el servidor
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','USER','PASS');
if(!$link){
    echo'No se pudo establecer conexion con el servidor:'.mysql_error();
}else{
    //Seleccionamos Base de datos
    $base=mysqli_select_db($link, 'DATABASE');
    if(!$base){
        echo'No se encontro la base de datos:'.mysqli_error();
    }else{
      //Sentencia SQL
      $sql= "SELECT * FROM datos";
      $ejecuta_sentencia = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
      if(!$ejecuta_sentencia){
          echo'Hay un error en la sentencia SQL:' .mysqli_error();
      }else{
          echo'Error al mostrar lista de usuarios:' .mysqli_error();
       }
    }

    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
        <title>Listado de Usuarios</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Mostrando Usuarios desde Base de Datos</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombres</th>
                <th>Correo Electronico</th>
                <th>Mensaje</th> <?php
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia)) {                              
                          echo"<tr>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['nombres']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                            echo"<td>".$row['message']."</td>";
                            echo"<td></td>";
                          echo"</tr>";
                        }

                    ?>

            <tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @alanfcm 
Hay manera de añadirle un contador de registros al final de la tabla? HE borrado el for y ya funciona bien

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que estás realizando un bucle y no lo cortas, por lo que se repetirá tantas veces como registros tengas.

Cierralo antes del cerrar el último con **endwhile**

Comment: Podrías indicarme en que parte va el cierre de endwhile y de que manera aplicarlo? gracias